# Set the number of blog posts - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Sorry guys this question may seem to be very basic. My CodeIgniter guy is not available and I couldn't find the answer online. I need to change the number of blog posts on the main blog reader page (the page that shows a small portion of the posts) to 10 or 12. atm I get only two 2 posts per page. As far as I remember I have to tweak things on site_configs.php file under config directory (maybe I am wrong I am not sure) Atm here is the settings:

```
$config['adm_perpage'] = 30;
$config['comment_perpage'] = 20;
$config['message_perpage'] = 50;
$config['home_perpage'] = 12;
$config ['feedper_page'] = 20;
```

Let me know if anything is unclear

Appreciate your help

Comment: maybe there are only 2 posts in database itself the code you have posted doesnot show that `Your CodeIgniter guy` has set them to 2 anywhere..

Comment: @plainjane Hi no there are 4 posts in the blog as well as in the database. strange!! isn't it?

Comment: there might be flags associated with blog posts such as active or published, so it might be showing two out of four!

Comment: you have any variable such as `$config['blog_perpage']` in your file from where you copy pasted this code

Answer (score 1):

This is specific to the code he wrote for you - you won't find the answer here unless you start posting half your codebase, and I doubt anyone will care to wade through that.

Best just wait till he's back

Comment: agreed `Best just wait till he's back`